# Limit Apache2.4 Request Header

Tags: apache, request-headers

The problem I'm tasked with is limiting a virtual host's request headers to only `POST`, `HEAD` and `GET` and require authentication for POST. I've done the first part by creating a `.htaccess` for my virtual host and typing in the following:

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
    Require all granted
</Limit>
```

I'm clueless on authentication for the request header POST, how do I that?

Comment: If you know which files produce POST requests, you can list them somehow in Files section. Example from [https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-filesmatch-and-files-in-htaccess/](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-filesmatch-and-files-in-htaccess/)
    <FilesMatch "^(admin|staff)\.php$">  
        AuthName "Dialog prompt"  
        AuthType Basic  
        AuthUserFile /web/username/.htpasswd  
        Require valid-user  
    </FilesMatch>

Comment: What do I do if my file produces both GET and POST request?